# How to match crowd database passwords?

Tags: pbkdf2, atlassian-crowd

I would like to have a piece of code that is able to check if a given password match the one stored in the crowd cwd_user table.

The passwords in that table starts with "{PKCS5S2}..." and I found in the link below that crowd is using the PBKDF2 algorithm:

> The default is "Atlassian Security", which is currently a dumb wrapper around Bouncy Castle's implementation of PKCS 5 version 2 (aka PBKDF2), using a random 16 byte salt, 10, 000 iterations, and generating a 256-bit hash as the final output

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/235858/password-security

Is anybody able to provide me a method I can use to match that password?

For example, if I create a user "toto" with password "1234", I get the following row in my database :

```
user_name     credential                                                                
------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
toto          {PKCS5S2}m+u8ed1RKRew3jjHPilZw0ICL6BG/qyeN+kVRRS9nsO+VK7Q5I0vCK3gLvCFWC3n
```

I would like a method such that:

```
public String getHash(String rowPassword){
    // ?????
}
```

where

```
getHash("1234") returns "{PKCS5S2}m+u8ed1RKRew3jjHPilZw0ICL6BG/qyeN+kVRRS9nsO+VK7Q5I0vCK3gLvCFWC3n"
```

Comment: Related: [`passlib.hash.atlassian_pbkdf2_sha1` - Atlassian’s PBKDF2-based Hash](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.atlassian_pbkdf2_sha1.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Crowd customer, you have access to the class [`AtlassianSecurityPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/2.7.1/com/atlassian/crowd/password/encoder/AtlassianSecurityPasswordEncoder.html) which is exactly that.

The underlying encoder chooses a random salt, ignoring the one passed in, so `encodePassword` won't give you the same hash each time. Use `isPasswordValid` to confirm that the password and hash match.

Comment: This solution works. In addition to this post, I had to add the maven artifact dependency "crowd-password-encoders". Simply using new AtlassianSecurityPasswordEncoder().isPasswordValid("{PKCS5S2}m+u8ed1RKRew3jjHPilZw0ICL6BG/qyeN+kVRRS9nsO+VK7Q5I0vCK3gLvCFWC3n","1234",null) do the trick.

Comment: See a full code sample here: https://bitbucket.org/caspar-atlassian/crowd-password-encoder-sample-app/overview